# Php Javascript How to remove the only text wanted from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do can I remove the only text "**You**" from the string and only left the text "**Kevin Yam, Bryan Ooi**"

Output : **Kevin Yam, Bryan Ooi**

```js
var panel = document.getElementById("panel" + (getlikeid));
var you = document.getElementById("only_you" + (getlikeid));

if (you.innerText === "You") {
  panel.remove();
} else if (you.innerText !== "You") {
  //execute code 
}
```

```html
<span id="only_you11"> You, Kevin Yam, Bryan Ooi</span>
```

Comment: Please be specific what output you want. It will be like this **Kevin Yam, Bryan Ooi**

Comment: How to remove php flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You `.replace()`

```js
var  text1 = $('span').text().replace(/You,/g, '')
$('span').text(text1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="only_you11"> You, Kevin Yam, Bryan Ooi</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know why the text() is not a function, so i change to -->      var  text1 = document.getElementById("only_you"+(getlikeid)).innerText.replace(/You,/g, '');
                                document.getElementById("only_you"+(getlikeid)).innerText = text1;

Comment: it is for jquery. i answered with jquery solution your solution will work because it is pure JS

Answer (score 0):

Just JS...

```
    var you = document.getElementById("only_you11");
            you.innerHTML = you.innerText.replace("You,", "");
```